# scp without known_hosts check

Tags: ssh, scp, known-hosts

Is there any chance to skip the `known_hosts` check without clearing `known_hosts` or disable it in `ssh.conf`? I neither have access to `known_hosts` nor `ssh.conf` yet.
Don't find any suitable in `man`.

Comment: what does "I neither have access to known_hosts nor ssh.conf yet. Don't find any suitable in man." mean? The `known_hosts` file is created once you have connected, so all should be fine.

Comment: Hi glglgl, that known_hosts is a file from another service user and visudo is not working correctly. So I have no writeable access to known_hosts nor ssh.conf. There is a false signature within that known_hosts file.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`scp` is supposed to take the same command line options as `ssh`, try:

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Maybe add `-q` to disable the warnings as well.

Answer (score 22):

For those of us who are less versed in Linux shorthand, the full syntax would look something like this:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r $source $user@$host:$destination
```